# Is this code returning milliseconds to seconds of epoch time

Tags: c, linux, datetime, winapi

I am linux programmer, was porting some windows code to Linux.

Here is a windows code snippet which I need to port.

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  static DWORD private_GetLongTime(void)
//
//      Function returns current time in the c-runtime format of the
//      number of milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970.
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
static DWORD private_GetLongTime(void)
{
    SYSTEMTIME SystemTime;
    DWORD dwDateTime = 0;
    WORD wYear = 1970;
    WORD wDays = 0;
    INT64 FileTime;
    INT64 FileTime2;
    INT64    SecondsSince1970;

    // read the current time
    GetSystemTime(&SystemTime);

    SystemTimeToFileTime(&SystemTime,(FILETIME *) &FileTime);

    SystemTime.wYear   = 1970;
    SystemTime.wMonth  = 1;
    SystemTime.wDay    = 1;
    SystemTime.wHour   = 0;
    SystemTime.wMinute = 0;
    SystemTime.wSecond = 0;
    SystemTime.wMilliseconds = 0;
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&SystemTime,(FILETIME *) &FileTime2);

    SecondsSince1970 = (INT64) FileTime - (INT64) FileTime2;

    dwDateTime = (DWORD ) (SecondsSince1970/ 10000000L);

    return dwDateTime;
}
```

Comment says it is returning milliseconds, but as per my understanding of the API's it is returning in seconds right.. Please confirm...

Comment: Why is code dividing by 10,000,000 in `dwDateTime = (DWORD ) (SecondsSince1970/ 10000000L);`?

Comment: To convert nano seconds into seconds

Comment: Yet there are 1,000,000,000 ns in 1 second, not 10,000,000.

Comment: FileTime returns in 100 nano seconds and not in 1 nano seconds

Comment: OK, so it is to covert 100 nano seconds to seconds, not nano seconds into seconds. Naked magic numbers (with no comments) have this problem. I suspect the comment returns current time in ... number of milliseconds is likely amiss too.

Comment: That code is hideous, I wouldn't trust it nor the comments. Variable names like `FileTime` and `FileTime2` carry no semantic meaning, needless avoidance of [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397.aspx), invalid `(INT64)` casts. It probably never did what it was intended to do: Return the current time as a UNIX Epoch time. Note that while documented to return UTC, the Windows API calls do not actually account for leap seconds, so they agree with UNIX Epoch time on that aspect, if only by accident.

Comment: NT system time is a `LARGE_INTEGER` in units of 100 ns since 1601-01-01. It's stored in `SharedUserData`, a memory section that's shared by all NT processes, and queried via WinAPI `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`. The interval between 1601-01-01 and 1970-01-01 is a constant 11644473600 seconds. There's even a (documented but not quite supported) runtime library function to do the conversion for you, [`RtlTimeToSecondsSince1970`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winternl/nf-winternl-rtltimetosecondssince1970).

Comment: @ery: The documentation for [FILETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx) implies, that it can be converted to a [ULARGE_INTEGER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_ularge_integer), not a `LARGE_INTEGER`. A tiny difference that's going to matter fairly soon-ish.

Comment: @IInspectable, NT time values are 64-bit signed integers. Absolute time is non-negative, and the year range is from 1601 to 30828. Negative time values are relative intervals, which are used for waits and timers. System time is a non-negative, absolute time. We can `memcpy` the `FILETIME` to a `LONGLONG` (i.e. `__int64`) or individually assign to corresponding fields of a `LARGE_INTEGER` (i.e. `dwLowDateTime` to `LowPart` and `dwHighDateTime` to `HighPart`) and use the `QuadPart` of the union.

Comment: @ery: This does not agree with the documentation or the data types. `FILETIME` consists of 2 `DWORD`s, i.e. unsigned values. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284.aspx) explicitly calls out using a `ULARGE_INTEGER` (again, unsigned) for arithmetic. Windows' ABI guarantees 2s-complement storage of signed values, so `memcpy`-ing an unsigned value into memory for a signed quantity is safe, but that doesn't mean, that time values are in fact signed values.

Comment: @IInspectable, to be clear, for NT systems, in `_KUSER_SHARED_DATA` (i.e. the struct for the section shared between NT processes and the kernel), the `SystemTime` field is a `_KSYSTEM_TIME`, which has the fields `ULONG LowPart`, `LONG High1Time`, and `LONG High2Time`. The `High2Time` field isn't relevant in the x64 ABI, so it's handled as a `LARGE_INTEGER` (carefully since it's not a union). If you disassemble x64 `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`, you'll see that it does a `QWORD` move from `SystemTime` to `rax` and then does two `DWORD` stores to move this 64-bit value into the `FILETIME` fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static DWORD private_GetLongTime(void)` returns seconds.

Comment: @md.jamal Yes, it is.